# Problems estimating anisotropy parameters for a spatial model

Tags: r, spatial

I am looking for someone with experience in how to handle the anisotropy-parameters in the `likfit()` function which is part of the [GeoR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoR/index.html) package in R.
I am using `likfit()` to generate the `obj.m`-parameter for the function `krige.conv()`. The data I use consists of scattered points (5 to 30) on a ~50*50 grid.

In `likfit()`, I want the parameters `psiA` and `psiR` to be estimated from the available data. This works fine by stating:

```
fix.psiA = FALSE, fix.psiR = FALSE
```

However, the estimated values show quite a huge range for `psiR`, given that the datasets I used are not fundamentaly different from each other. (It is a set of soil moisture measurements with values from 0 to ~45.)

`psiR` ranges from 1 to about 8000... can that be right? Most of the values are in a range from 1 to 10, but I can not tell why some datasets produce these very large values for `psiR`.

I was unable to find further information on what this parameter *exactly* does. I do understand that this parameter regulates the dependency of an estimated value according to it's location relative to the ambient measured values. But I do not know in which way this is accomplished.

I am sorry for not posting my code, but it is quite long and I felt that it is not necessary in behalf of my question.

Thank you very much for your interest. I will post additional details, if required.

Comment: This question is *squarely* on topic here, even though it is couched in the context of particular software. It asks about estimating a spatial generalized linear model (and this R package happens to be about the only one that does it).

Comment: @whuber, as a close voter, I'll just say my thought was that this seems to be asking what a particular argument, `psiR`, does, not about the statistical model (btw: it's not quite clear to me what package the OP is using but I don't think it's the only one that fits spatial GLMs - `spBayes` and `geoRglm` both can).

Comment: @Macro:I am using GeoR, as stated in the title. I am sorry for not unsing more appropriate tags, but there were no. There is no tag for "GeoR", left alone "likfit".

Comment: @Macro I appreciate your reasoning and agree with it. However, I hope that my answer demonstrates the sense in which this question goes beyond any particular package. (I lump `geoRglm` in with `geoR` because they are typically used together and documented together. `spBayes` uses a different approach.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, **identifying anisotropy is hopeless with these sparse data**.

The two parameters in question, `psiA` and `psiR`, describe anisotropy (the angle and ratio, respectively, of a "geometric anisotropy": consult [GSLIB](http://www.gslib.com/) or [Journel & Huijbregts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1930665911) for details, because the `geoR` documentation in [Diggle & Ribeiro Jr](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/mbgbook/) is indeed inadequate concerning anisotropy). With relatively few datapoints it is quite possible--indeed, with soils data (which can be notoriously variable) it is quite likely--that in some directions almost no spatial correlation is detected while in other directions there appears to be some correlation. This can result in near-infinite ratios.  Also, if there is a trend in just one direction and it is not removed, this trend will create a strong anisotropy.

Your problem is that five points are *way* too few for any kind of parameter estimation and $30$ are still too few to identify anisotropy reliably. Rules of thumb in the literature suggest you need *at a minimum* between $30$ and $100$ points just to get started with estimating the parameters and computing the predictions (that is, kriging).  (All rules of thumb have exceptions, but it sounds like these data are not nice enough to qualify.)  If you do not assume an isotropic model, you need to explore directional variograms in at least four cardinal directions, whence each such variogram would be based on approximately $5$ to $10$ points each, which again is too small.  To identify anisotropy, figure on needing about $100$ points.

The cure is to impose isotropic variograms (or determine anisotropy from considerations independent of the data) and hope for the best.  Expect the prediction errors to be large.

Comment: @ whuber: Thank you very much for your detailed post. I spend the last half hour looking on contour plots of the interpolated data unsing a variety of values for psiR. It looks as if any value above 5 is due to an unfortunate spatial relation between measurement points and a general lack of points. All datasets with ~30 points give an estimation for psiR of about 1-2. So it looks like as if I just have to use an average value obtained from the "better" datasets. I was hoping I could avoid that. Again, thank you very much for your post and the literature, I will dig in it.

Comment: If you have multiple related datasets (such as data sampled over time), you can "borrow strength" by combining them for estimating a common variogram. At a minimum, related data might suggest the direction (`psiA`) and amount (`psiR`) of anisotropy, which you can then impose on `likfit`. If you're getting `psiR` only in the 1-2 range, you might be best off assuming isotropy: the additional parsimony (the model uses two fewer parameters) can be an advantage.

Comment: The datasets are related as follows: I have five datasets for 10 plots each. the datasets for each plot represent 2d soil moisture for a vertical profile, distance between profiles is 20 cm. I will try do combine them, even though I don't think that this will solve the problem, since "blank spots" in the measurements are mostly present in the same spots of the five profiles, due to soil compaction etc. Regarding the assumtion of isotropy: I don't think I should do this here, since the project is about the infiltration-front, which is - by definition - not isotrop. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You really have a 3D problem but not enough data. However, if you assume a common *horizontal* covariance structure for each profile (which may be physically reasonable), independent of depth, you *can* combine these for 2D analysis using a simple trick: just horizontally translate each depth into a new set of locations so far away from the other depths that they won't interfere, and now do the variography.  That will multiply the available point-pairs by a factor of $5$, which is numerically about the same as (and statistically better than) having $2.2$ times as much data.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correct. Do you propose to transfer the five profiles into one grid, but expand the grid in order to avoid measurement points at close locations? Or do you mean to horizontaly string them together (with some space in between)? In the first case, I would not get 5 times as much data because of some coincident locations, but still an advance. By the way: Thank you for editing my opening post. I wasn't proud of it ether.

Comment: Addendum: Ok, I think I understand what you mean: Put the datasets in the same grid (in their original spatial allignment with the original grid resolution), but with lots of space between the points for each profile, right? That is a very very good idea, I will put that into execution immediately.

Comment: Update: I was able to produce reasonable values by unsing the suggestions from whuber, even though some plots (with sparse data) still don't show any signs of anistropy. But I guess I have to live with that.